# Updating BehaviorSubject using it's own data

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have the following code:

```
summaries$: BehaviorSubject<IncidentSummary[]> = new BehaviorSubject(new Array<IncidentSummary>(0));

onSearchTextChanged(val: any) {
        this.summaries$.subscribe(data => this.summaries$.next(data.filter(summary => 
           summary.name.startsWith(val)
        || summary.type.startsWith(val))));
}
```

Basically I'm filtering the data of a BehaviorSubject based on search text. Problem is that this code causes an infinite loop. I tried `unsubscrib`ing from within the subscribe that doesn't help. So how do I use the data to pass on to `BehaviorSubject.next`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't subscribe to get the data. You may store the full data array in an own property and just call `next` with the new filtered data you calculated from the full data and the search text.

Comment: If really want to do incremental computations you may use `BehaviorSubject`'s `getValue` method to get the current value. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md